# Graph theory and degree of vertex

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

A given tree with 9 vertices has precisely five vertices of degree 1, and precisely two vertices of degree 2. The remaining two vertices have degrees $a$ and $b$. Given that $a \le b$, determine $a$ and $b$.

Comment: "*given that `a x- b`*"  What does this mean?

Comment: "*A given* **tree**"  Remember that a tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges.  Remember that the sum of degrees is twice the number of edges.  These two facts should give you enough to continue.

Comment: A particular tree with 9 vertices has precisely five vertices of degree 1, and precisely two vertices of degree 2. The remaining two vertices have degrees a and b. Find a and b, given that a ≤ b.

Comment: please @JMoravitz this is the right question

Comment: A particular tree with 9 vertices has precisely five vertices of degree 1, and precisely two vertices of degree 2. The remaining two vertices have degrees a and b. Find a and b, given that a ≤ b.

Comment: i still dont know how to continue. i am thinking i have to form equation @JMoravitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $d \ge 1$, let $n_d$ be the number of vertices of degree $d$.  Then
\begin{align}
\sum_d n_d &= 9 \\
\sum_d d n_d &= 2(9-1)
\end{align}
Substituting $n_1=5$ and $n_2=2$ yields
$$1\cdot 5 + 2\cdot 2 + a + b = 16,$$
so
$$a + b = 7.$$
Now what does $3 \le a \le b$ imply?

Comment: thanks, but the question say find a and b given that a ≤ b. a and b represents the degrees. 3≤a≤b  implies that a is greater than or equal to 3, while b is greater than or equal to a and 3.

Comment: @ojei what ways can you add up two whole numbers to get 7? 1+6 is one way... 2+5 is another way... We had learned that $a$ and $b$ are two whole numbers who add up to $7$ and that neither are equal to $1$ or $2$... what else could they be?

Comment: 3 and 4. So a is 3, why b is 4. Thanks for the helpful info.

Comment: Yes.  Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.